# Cypress. How skip part of autotest if "if part couldn't be find"

Tags: automation, cypress

So, I practice Cypress.
I can't find information, how i can skip "if" part, if it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIUJb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv6yI.png)

```
describe('test that XPath from task does not work and change non-breaking space', () => {
it('passes', () => {
  cy.visit('http://uitestingplayground.com/nbsp')
  if (cy.xpath('//button[text()="My Button"]').click()) {
    cy.log('Button found and clicked.')
  }
  else {
    cy.xpath('//button[text()="My\u00a0Button"]').click()
    cy.log('Button found and clicked. But was problem with non-breaking space in XPath.')
  }
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this. Here `length > 0` will check if the element is present in the DOM.

```js
describe('test that XPath from task does not work and change non-breaking space', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('http://uitestingplayground.com/nbsp')

    cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
      if ($body.find('button selector').length > 0) {
        cy.xpath('//button[text()="My Button"]').click()
        cy.log('Button found and clicked.')
      } else {
        cy.xpath('//button[text()="My\u00a0Button"]').click()
        cy.log(
          'Button found and clicked. But was problem with non-breaking space in XPath.'
        )
      }
    })
  })
})
```